# passing an integer with "|" sign using java

Tags: java, methods, parameters, int, jna

I have a C code which has the below line.

```
ipj_set_value(&iri_device,E_IPJ_KEY_REPORT_CONTROL_TAG,E_IPJ_TAG_FLAG_BIT_EPC | E_IPJ_TAG_FLAG_BIT_TID |E_IPJ_TAG_FLAG_BIT_TIMESTAMP | E_IPJ_TAG_FLAG_BIT_CHANNEL);
```

I am calling this set value method from Java using JNA. How do I do the same in Java? That is I want to pass many integers using "|" sign. This functions as "or" here. Below is the method definition and the variables I have used above.

```
ipj_error ipj_set_value(
    ipj_iri_device *iri_device, /**< [in] IRI device data structure */
    ipj_key         key,        /**< [in] Key code to set*/
    uint32_t        value)      /**< [in] Value to set */
 {
    return ipj_set(iri_device, key, 0, 0, value);
 }

#define E_IPJ_TAG_FLAG_BIT_EPC       ((ipj_tag_flag)(0x1))
#define E_IPJ_TAG_FLAG_BIT_TID       ((ipj_tag_flag)(0x2))
#define E_IPJ_TAG_FLAG_BIT_TIMESTAMP ((ipj_tag_flag)(0x20))
#define E_IPJ_TAG_FLAG_BIT_CHANNEL   ((ipj_tag_flag)(0x100))
```

Comment: The same? Have you tried?

Comment: Yes. I am getting a number format exception while trying to convert the "1|64" to int format. I am getting this as a string from my websocket client.

Comment: you need to pass it as string

Comment: @VD' my method declaration should be equivalent to that of the C code. Its expecting an integer param. So can't pass it as a string

Comment: Of course, "1|64" is not a valid integer. Not in C, not in Java. If you really allow your Javascript client to determine this value, then you should evaluate this expression "1|64" in Javascript and pass the resulting value (65) to Java.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt its a key-value concept. A key is having multiple values. So though the method declaration in C is expecting an int, I am able to pass all the value integers using "|" sign. 64 and 1 mean different things for this key.

Comment: @ajb I am not asking about string split.

Comment: If you receive a string in the form of "1|64" from a websocket in C, then you cannot parse that as an integer. 1|64 is a valid expression in C source code and in Java source code. But it's not a valid integer that you can parse with atoi, Integer.parseInt or whatever function you use to convert a string to an integer.

Comment: Then I have no clue what you're asking.  You said you're trying to convert `"1|64"` to `int` format and getting a number format exception.  That implies to me that at some point, you have a string whose value is the four characters `1`, `|`, `6`, `4`.  And you're trying to convert this to an integer?  You'll need to calculate it.  Which means you'll need to extract the numbers between the `|` signs.  Which means... `split()`.  If you meant something different, your question is confusing.

Comment: The method you are going to call (which exposed by JNA) is expecting an integer, then pass an integer? why would you construct a string consist of integer and `|`, and convert back to the corresponding integer?  Just do `your_jna_method(whatever, whatever, 1|2|4|8)`

Comment: Can you show us the Java code that you're using to call this C function?

Answer (score 2):

Even you accepted already an answer. I believe it's worth to correct it.

`|` is the logical `OR` operator. The values are not **added**. It will perform a **bitwise** `OR` operation (see: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR)).

A small example snippet.

```
static final int E_IPJ_TAG_FLAG_BIT_EPC = 1;
static final int E_IPJ_TAG_FLAG_BIT_TID = 2;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("00000000");
    sb.append(Integer.toBinaryString(E_IPJ_TAG_FLAG_BIT_EPC));
    System.out.println("E_IPJ_TAG_FLAG_BIT_EPC: " + sb.substring(sb.length()-8));

    sb.delete(8, sb.length());
    sb.append(Integer.toBinaryString(E_IPJ_TAG_FLAG_BIT_TID));
    System.out.println("E_IPJ_TAG_FLAG_BIT_TID: " + sb.substring(sb.length()-8));

    int orEd = E_IPJ_TAG_FLAG_BIT_EPC | E_IPJ_TAG_FLAG_BIT_TID;
    sb.delete(8, sb.length());
    sb.append(Integer.toBinaryString(orEd));
    System.out.println("bitwise OR            : " + sb.substring(sb.length()-8));
}
```

output

```
E_IPJ_TAG_FLAG_BIT_EPC: 00000001
E_IPJ_TAG_FLAG_BIT_TID: 00000010
bitwise OR            : 00000011
```

If `|` would mean to add the values then `E_IPJ_TAG_FLAG_BIT_EPC | E_IPJ_TAG_FLAG_BIT_EPC` would be `00000010`. As it's a bitwise OR the result is still `00000001`.

Answer (score 1):

Java has a bitwise or operator, just like C:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

You should be able to code it just the same way as you do in C.

Comment: I am receiving this "1|64" as an integer from a websocket client. so when I convert this to int, I am getting a number format exception.

Comment: @mayooran Then how would that work in C? *It wouldn't.*
 The websocket client is sending the wrong data, because it's supposed to send `65`, not `1|64`.

Answer (score -1):

When you use two integers combined with "|" you are actually adding them. Therefore get the string splits and do an addition and pass the added value

Comment: | is not an integer addition, it is a bitwise OR